# Does QSFP+ require 4 fibers?

Tags: cisco, switch, sfp

I am currently designing a network, and there are 2 fibers between 2 switches. Can I use a 40Gbit QSFP+ module to achieve this speed or is 10Gbit SFP the best possible without adding more fibers?

Comment: You can run up to 100G on one single OS2 singlemode fiber.

Comment: You should make this an answer, @Cown, so it can be accepted and the answer can be closed.

Comment: @TeunVink thanks, i can see Zac67 made a good answer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QSFP+ is just the transceiver interface. Medium compatibility and reach is defined by the PHY used by the fitted transceiver.

While the short-range 40GBASE-SR4 PHY requires four separate multi-mode fibers per direction (OM3 or OM4), 40GBASE-LR4 (CWDM) or -FR (single-lane) use only one fiber per direction - both require single-mode fiber, however. Both will work on short MMF runs as well - unspecified though.

Beyond the official IEEE 802.3 PHYs there's a range of other types available - many from third-party vendors.